# Replacing Axiom of Choice with Axiom of Countable Choice

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Many people find ACC more intuitive than AC ("Pick something from the first set, then something from the second set, then...) and it also doesn't lead to "controversial consequences" (See for eg: [Peculiar examples with Axiom of Countable Choice ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23246/peculiar-examples-with-axiom-of-countable-choice))

My question is:
What are the consequences for Set Theory if we replace AC by ACC -as in ZF and ACC assumed true but cannot assume AC ?

Specifically:
1) Are all ZFC ordinals - $\aleph_1$, $\aleph_\omega$, aleph and beth fixed points etc - still well-defined ?
2) Is the Continuum Hypothesis still undecidable ?
3) Are there any striking changes to Large Cardinal properties ? (For eg: "The smallest measurable cardinal can be equal to the smallest strongly inaccessible cardinal")

PS: If the question is too broad, I'd be very happy to be referred to a book/paper.

Edited: Realized from a comment below that ZF + ACC + Not AC was the system I had in mind, otherwise question 2 becomes trivial.

Comment: I thought it was automatic that, if you weaken an axiomatic theory, then anything that was undecidable before is still undecidable?

Comment: Following on what bof said in his first comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number

Comment: Very interesting. I am editing my question accordingly.

Comment: Surely, if CH could be proved or disproved with ACC, then it could be proved or disproved in set theory with the full AC? So why is 2) a question?

Comment: None of the usual basic theory of alephs uses choice, only the assertion that every cardinal is an aleph.

Comment: Bof: My question is the other way around. I am replacing AC by ACC. 
So, not clear to me if you can even construct a model of ZF + ACC where CH holds. Also, not sure if forcing requires full AC.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes. 3) Yes. How could $\mathsf{CH}$ not be undecidable, by the way, if it is undecidable in the stronger theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$? Any standard reference should address this. For instance, Jech's set theory book.

Comment: Any model of ZF + AC + CH is also a model of ZF + ACC + CH. Likewise, any model of ZF + AC + not-CH is also a model of ZF + ACC + not-CH.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo How are limit beth cardinals defined in ZF? How is "strongly inaccessible defined"? If strongly inaccessible cardinals exist, is there necessarily a smallest one?

Comment: @bof Well, for any set $X$ and any ordinal $\alpha$ I can define $\beth_\alpha(X)$ in the usual way; the key axiom is *replacement*, not choice. As for strong inaccessiblity, that's usually understood to be a property of *well-orderable* cardinals, i.e. $\aleph$s, so the usual definition works the same way.

Comment: @bof Ah, didn't even notice the beths there. Sure, limit beths are not well defined. There are several ways of defining inaccessibility that are now not equivalent, there are recent papers addressing this. (But this is not a problem.) And no, of course you lose the existence of minimal witnesses.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Why are limit beths not defined? If I give you a set $X$ and an arbitrary ordinal $\alpha$, I can define the iterated powerset $P_\alpha(X)$, and then let $\beth_\alpha(X)$ be the (probably not well-orderable but oh well) cardinality of this powerset. Am I missing something?

Comment: @NoahSchweber In defining what it means for a *well-orderable* regular limit cardinal $\aleph_\alpha$ to be strongly inaccessible, do you require $\kappa\lt\aleph_\alpha\implies2^\kappa\lt\aleph_\alpha$ or merely $\kappa\lt\aleph_\alpha\implies2^\kappa\not\ge\aleph_\alpha$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, sure, we can do that.

Comment: @bof That's a good point, I spoke too soon.

Comment: @Cosmonut Maybe you want to focus on models of ZF+ACC+$\neg$AC, to make things less trivial? Note, though, that this doesn't really impact anything "low down" like CH: we can have the first failure of choice happen way high up in the cumulative hierarchy.

Comment: Actually, there is an old paper by Keisler and Morley where they provide a definition of beth cardinals as well-ordered cardinalities that allows them to prove the Erdős–Rado theorem in $\mathsf{ZF}$. Of course, their beths are not the sizes of iterated power sets. We could go with this definition, why not?

Comment: @Cosmonut Re: large cardinals, if you don't already know about this: assuming AD, **$\omega_1$ is measurable**! (So is $\omega_2$ - this is harder to prove. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33468/measurable-cardinals-under-axiom-of-determinacy) So . . . that's weird!

Comment: @Cosmonut Question 2 is still trivial, since we can have only "high-rank" failures of choice.

Comment: That's truly incredible ! Thanks for the edit suggestion, BTW. Realized that ZF + "Can assume ACC but not AC" was really what I had in mind - so was getting puzzled by the downvotes.

Comment: What you describe is not $\sf AC_\omega$. It's $\sf DC$, which is strictly stronger.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, the axiom of countable choice says that given a countable family of non-empty sets, you can choose from each set *simultaneously*. If you want to choose from one, then from another, then from another, and so on you need a strictly stronger form of choice called **Dependent Choice**, abbreviated as $\sf DC$.

To your questions, the definition of the $\aleph$ numbers uses absolutely no choice, although the proof that any of them is regular does use the axiom of choice (well, except $\aleph_0$). So it is consistent, for example, that $\aleph_1$ is singular. But assuming $\sf DC$ will prevent that. Whether or not you can have every cardinal $\geq\aleph_2$ singular with $\sf ZF+DC$ is still open.

The definition of $\beth$ numbers, on the other hand, goes out the window. The axiom of choice is equivalent to saying that the power set of a well-ordered set is well-ordered. So if the axiom of choice fails, there will be some ordinal $\alpha$ whose power set cannot be well-ordered. This means that at some point $\beth$ cardinals will not be $\aleph$ numbers. You can still talk about $\beth$ numbers, of course, as iterated powers of $\omega$, but that gives you significantly less information in that sense.

As for the continuum hypothesis, as noted by others it is still unprovable. But now you even get different forms of the continuum hypothesis. $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ is no longer equivalent to "Every uncountable set of reals is equipollent with the reals themselves". Indeed, even without $\sf DC$, it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $\aleph_1$ are incomparable, and every uncountable set of reals has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Finally, for large cardinals, most properties which are reserved for very large cardinals can be made compatible with $\aleph_1$ and $\sf ZF+DC$. For a more complete survey, look at [What sort of large cardinal can $\aleph_1$ be without the axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87430/what-sort-of-large-cardinal-can-aleph-1-be-without-the-axiom-of-choice).